# No such file or directory during AWS EC2 Instance SSH Connection

Tags: linux, ssh, mac, amazon-ec2

I am on the macOS terminal using Bash:

```
$ cd downloads/
$ chmod 400 uindo-ssh-key.pem
```

Response:

```
chmod: pem: No such file or directory
```

This issue is rising even I am having the PEM file in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

#### Run the below commands

Move to directory path:

```
cd ~/downloads
```

Are you in correct directory path (`/Users/user/downloads`)?

```
pwd
```

List all files:

```
ls -l;
```

If the file "uindo-ssh-key.pem" exists run the command to change the permissions to 400:

```
chmod 400 uindo-ssh-key.pem
```